# Get a id from the formbuilder to delete a row in Angular 6

Tags: html, angular, typescript, http, .net-core

I have a HTML page with a few forms to fill in for the user:

```
<div class="card-body">
  <form [formGroup]="FormCar" (ngSubmit)="AddCar(FormCar.value)">
    <input type="hidden" formControlName="CarId" id="carId" />
    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
        <label>Brand</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="Brand" id="brand" placeholder="Enter brand">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
        <label>Model</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="Model" id="model" placeholder="Enter model">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
        <label>Color</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="Color" id="color" placeholder="Enter color">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
        <label>Speed</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" formControlName="TopSpeed" id="topSpeed" placeholder="Enter speed">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group mr-2">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger mr-1">Save changes</button>
      <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger mr-1">New record</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger mr-1" (click)="DeleteCar(CarId)">Delete</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

I use a HTML table to display data and when the user clicks on a row it fill with the **inputs** information. I used this method to fill the fields:

```
EditCar(carId: number) {
    this.carservice.getCarById(carId).subscribe((res: any) => {
      this.FormCar.patchValue({
        CarId: res.carId,
        Brand: res.brand,
        Model: res.model,
        Color: res.color,
        TopSpeed: res.topSpeed
      })
    });
  }
```

This is working good I have build my form with **formbuilder** like this:

```
  buildFormCar() {
    this.FormCar = this.formBuilder.group({
      CarId: ['', Validators.required],
      Brand: ['', Validators.required],
      Model: ['', Validators.required],
      Color: ['', Validators.required],
      TopSpeed: ['', Validators.required],
    });
  }
```

After the fields are filled I want to delete it by his **id** and I use this method for it:

```
DeleteCar(carId: string) {
    if (confirm("Weet u zeker?")) {
      this.carservice.deleteCar(carId).subscribe(() => {
        this.GetCar();
        this.GetCarCount();         
      })
    }
  }
```

When I click on the delete button I get a error on the backend (I use .NET core)

This is the error message:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The property 'CarId' on entity type
>   'Car' has a temporary value while attempting to change the entity's
>   state to 'Deleted'. Either set a permanent value explicitly or ensure
>   that the database is configured to generate values for this property.'

The method that I use in the backend look like this:

```
 [Route("DeleteCar")]
 [HttpDelete]
 public IActionResult Delete(long id)
 {
   _context.Cars.Remove(new Car() { CarId = id });
   _context.SaveChanges();
   return Ok();
 }
```

It seems it cannot find the `carId` when the **delete** happens.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `FormCar.get("CarId").value` like this:

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger mr-1" (click)="DeleteCar(FormCar.get("CarId").value)">Delete</button>
```

or Donot pass any parameter in `DeleteCar()` and do this:

```
DeleteCar() {
    if (confirm("Weet u zeker?")) {
      this.carservice.deleteCar(this.FormCar.get("CarId").value).subscribe(() => {
        this.GetCar();
        this.GetCarCount();         
      })
    }
  }
```